# Extending the default Forms module

Tags: forms, telerik, sitefinity

Is there any way to extend an built in module? I need to add a datepicker in section : "Settings to control form behavior", where the user could select a date of publish/unpublish a form.
[check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guGJd.png)

Is this even possible?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to set Publish/Unpublish date on the Page that is holding the form?

Comment: I can't. The forms will be kind of polls, and it's just a small part of the entire page.

Comment: Then you can add a custom ScheduledTask that will execute on a specified date and will unpublish the form.
So, maybe create a custom backend page where you show a list of all forms and a date. Upon selecting the form and the date and clicking submit you can create a scheduled task that will run on the selected date/time and unpublish the form. That seems like the best way to do it.